# Problem using AllocConsole() and marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, .net-4.0

I've got a C# application that calls a native C++ DLL (I control the source of both). I've used AllocConsole() from the managed side, and then call into the native side. But the native code won't output to the console- nothing happens, even though there is most definitely a console available, since I just explicitly allocated one. The code works fine if I allocate a console before the first console output from the native code, but if I try to allocate a console during only some std::cout calls, then it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: Creating the console window *before* the CRT initializes stdout is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is not linked to use the console subsystem, you have to [hook it up yourself](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm).

Comment: You know, that link is thirteen years old, and describes a version of Visual Studio five prior to the one I'm using, right? std::ios::sync_with_stdio() causes the output to be redirected- to the VS output window, not the console.

Comment: It has worked fine for me in the past using a native application and Visual Studio 2005; maybe it's an issue with managed applications.

Comment: I figured it out.  Visual Studio is redirecting standard output to its output window.  You can get around this by (temporarily) resetting the standard output handle with CreateFile("CONOUT$") and SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE).  Not sure of the ramifications of this, though.